# Redirect to external site on 500 error with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am working on a website (scratchyone.com). I need to have my .htaccess redirect to an external page

```
http://scratchywon.github.io/scratchyone.com/errors/500.html
```

on a 500 error. I am forcing a 500 with php.

```
http://scratchyone.com/500/
```

Here is my current code:

```
ErrorDocument 500 http://scratchywon.github.io/scratchyone.com/errors/500.html
```

EDIT: `ErrorDocument 404 http://scratchywon.github.io/scratchyone.com/errors/500.html` works
Now that I am using php to send the 500 error, the page doesn't display. It just displays the browser's default "500: Could not display"

Comment: What is the problem with your error document?

Comment: it's really hard to determine what would be wrong without a more complete .htaccess post, without knowing your server environment and without posting any errors you may be getting either on your browser or in your httpd logs..  update your question with more details.

Comment: It is giving the default 500 error message.

Comment: Your .htaccess might not be enabled

Comment: No, because it works for 404 error pages.

Comment: Testing htaccess error handling (500 in this case) by adding a broken .htaccess sounds like trouble.  Try adding a simple php script that returns a 500 instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internal error in .htaccess not relay custom ErrorDocument (!) and simulate 500 error via PHP is not quite possible - when your script run it's too late - error document redirection is handled by apache mod_core (!) and PHP only send status.
So I think you can forget about PHP 500-simulation.

Try to make a directory next to main .htaccess and inside make faulty .htaccess

Or maybe this will be helpful for you:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-apache-to-use-custom-error-pages-on-ubuntu-14-04

Section about 500 provide information how to simulate this error via bad proxy.

Comment: Sadly, I can't test this, because my host does not enable proxy_pass, but this is correct.